# How do I exactly alias this one liner in bash?

Tags: linux, terminal, alias, fzf

bash alias doesn't like the quotes

```
dpkg-query -W -f '${Installed-Size;8}kb ${Package} ${Version} ${Status}\n' | sort -n | column -t | grep -Pv "(lib*)" | fzf
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest using a function instead. That will avoid all the quoting issues:

```bash
your_function_name() {
  dpkg-query -W -f '${Installed-Size;8}kb ${Package} ${Version} ${Status}\n' \
  | sort -n \
  | column -t \
  | grep -Pv "(lib*)" \
  | fzf "$@"
}
```